# Как работать с fifo в linux kernel?

Tags: linux, c, kernel, fifo

Не могу найти пример, как прочитать данные в fifo. 
В user mode я создаю fifo и записываю данные, вот пример:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include<unistd.h>   
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<pthread.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define MAX_BUF 999999

int main()
{ int i;
int fd,d=0;
char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo3";
char buf[MAX_BUF],src[]="1234567890qwertyuiop",src2[2]="98";
if((mkfifo(myfifo, 0666)) == -1)
{
fprintf(stderr, "Невозможно создать fifo\n");

} else{mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);}
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    for (i=99999999;i>0;i--){

    if(fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY)== -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Невозможно открыть fifo\n");   
    }else {
        d=1+(int) (10.0*rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0));
        src[0]=src[d];
        write(fd, src, sizeof(src));
        close(fd);
        }

    }
return 0;
}
```

А как работать с fifo в kernel linux?

Comment: А зачем вам fifo к ядре ? это мягко говоря нетривиально. вам скорее всего придется создавать отдельный процесс уровня ядра для работы с ним. Для подобных целей в ядре существует механизм /proc и стоит работать через него, а не через fifo

Comment: А механизм /proc позволяет запись\чтение в неблокирующем режиме?

Comment: В nix системах с любым объектом типа файла можно работать неблокирующе. поставьте соответствующие флаги через fcntl и работайте. Если вдруг стандартные обработчики /proc этого не позволяют вы через структуру file_operations можете навесить любые обработчики которые нужны вам. В том числе обработать флаги O_NONBLOCK и когда они установлены возвращать управление из функций чтения/записи с соответствующими ошибками когда буфера приема полны или буфера передачи пусты

Comment: например fs/proc/kmsg.c: kmsg_read() умеет обрабатывать O_NONBLOCK и судя по его единственной строчке отвечающей за это, делается элементарно, как я и сказал, смотрим флаг в структуре файла и если он есть проверяем можем ли мы выполнить операцию прямо сейчас, если нет - возвращаем `-EAGAIN`

Comment: @Mike, спасибо большое! Тогда ещё один вопрос, а usermode приложение может делать запись в proc?

Comment: Что такое "делать запись". Если модуль который объявил данный файл имеет обработчик записи в файл - то можно писать в такой файл из usermode. Думаю можно написать обработчики и для создания новых файлов, хотя точно не уверен, надо изучать ядро

Comment: @Mike, я имел в виду, может ли usermode приложение изменять содержимое в proc. К примеру я создал модулем файл proc/test, он пуст, а usermod приложение будет изменять содержимое этого файла

Comment: Ну так я и сказал, если модуль на стороне ядра задал функцию обработчик записи (file_operations->write) - то может. Все файлы в /proc/sys так и работают, через них userspace пишет настройки в ядро.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: @Mike, и не только. Любой ABI можно использовать для коммуникации с ядром. Вопрос только какой подходит из них лучше.